Getting updates from 20 modbus slaves very frequently
For a past few months I'm playing around with ESP boards flashed with ESPHome and using them in Home assistant. They are working great but I was wondering if there is a way to communicate between nodes in some wired way instead of WiFi. Then I came across modbus and it seemed pretty good, so I bought some RS485 to TTL converters and tried some basic controlling. Currently I know how to control relays or read temperature sensors for example from the slave ESP's, all from the master ESP.
So I was thinking about making some kind of "smart wall switch" as slave devices, which would have a few inputs for the beginning. But of course I would need to check the state of these inputs very frequently, let's say every 200ms and this would overwhelm the bus if there was for example 20 of these switches all around the house and some other relays modules and so on. So I was wondering if there is some more efficient way to get real-time states from these switches without overwhelming the bus.

Modbus RTU doesn't specify one specific baudrate, you can easily run it >=115kbaud. If you just need some binary states, a Tx Rx exchange is <10+10 bytes. Should be possible to access quite a few nodes pr second - at least well over 5.

@MrGerber I have tested to poll 1 register with the all the states from 3 nodes at 115kbps with update interval set to 300ms, but it seemed like it is not doing great. I had a lot of warnings in the ESPHome logs saying something like "Multiple modbus command to device...". So I could not image doing this with ~20 nodes.

I routinely use Modbus to read 10+ devices with >10 registers pr request, with polling rate way more frequent than 3Hz. On 9600 baud. Its not an issue for Modbus - that sounds like an issue with the master you're using. Or the slave stack.

@MrGerber are you also using ESP's with the RS485 converters?

No, I use PC with pymodbus or Modbus Poll as master, and a slave stack implemented by myself and my colleague. RS485 transceivers are required of course.

@k0cka One issue might be your random RS-485 boards. We don't know what boards they are and how you use them. Otherwise, you can run the bus at 10 Mbps or whatever the transceivers, the ESPs, or the bus wiring allows.

@Justme I use this rs485 board for the master - https://prnt.sc/eg8xRoQ99ajt and this board for the slaves - https://prnt.sc/6lk_1uVtdkY9. The reason why I use different board for the master is because when I used the same as I am using for the slaves with the auto flow control, it was slow and it felt like it was giving weak signals or what. Also I couldn't read registers, I could only write but it was very unreliable. And another thing is that I have everything wired up on breadboard, so the wiring is not ideal either.

@Justme So do you think if I would have "ideal circumstances", it wouldn't be a problem to read that many slaves that frequently? Is it a standard practice?

this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pjon&ia=web

The auto-enabling modules may keep the transmit enabled too long. Unless you don't know, measure the hardware timing and verify your software is compatible with it. Or the hardware is compatible with software.

@jsotola hm it looks interesting, I will definitely take a closer look on that, thanks!

@Justme I don't know how to do that yet unfortunately. Is there a way to fix the transmit time? I tried to rewire the connections a little more precisely and it seems like it's better now. It's still not perfect but I'm getting a lot less warning messages about duplicate modbus command than before.

@MrGerber oh I just noticed you edited your message. Im using ESP-12F modules for master and also for slaves for now. I feel like that maybe the auto flow control converters are not behaving as expected, as Justme pointed out. Or what issue did you meant?
